# Can we use event.target to transform (translateX) for every iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I want to add `$(event.target)` to translate my card for every iteration. Is that possible? What should I do?

I tried this way: `$(event.target.i).css('transform', 'translate(300px)');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var n = $('#move .card').length;

  function addDot(i) {
    var newDot = (`<span class="dot" data-index="${i}" id ="${i}" </span>`);
    $('.myDiv').append(newDot);
    
    $('#' + i).click(function(event) {
      $(event.target.i).css('transform', 'translate(300px)');
    });
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    addDot(i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card ">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-avatar-1/512/10_avatar-512.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100px">
  <div class="containers">
    <h2>Great Experience !</h2>
    <button>Relax Plan</button>
    <div class="contain">
      <p>I found the servive very prompt. I would also suggest my friends to take this plan. I am going to suggest this to my friends as well</p><br>
      <h3>Virat Kohli</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hit f12 & let us know if there are any console errors?

Comment: There's no error